# .gitignore stopped working after VS re-install

Tags: git, visual-studio

I needed to reinstall my Visual Studio. I have several projects (ASP.NET, Angular) which are in Azure remote repo, also using .gitignore and thus far no problems at all.

After the mentioned reinstallation of Visual Studio for some reason the gitignore files are not working and unnecessary files are in the changes. Why this issue happens and how can I overcome it? No changes to the project were made at all (in VS or in the folder structure)

I tried with `git rm --cached` but Bash says "fatal: No pathspec was given. Which files should I remove?"

Comment: Do you mean `re-install`? If not, what does `pre-install` mean?

Comment: Yes, re install. I will fix the typo. I removed Visual Studio and then installed it again, without changing my projects.

Comment: as the error message indicates : you should type `git rm --cached path/to/some/file` (not `git rm --cached` alone)

Comment: I still am not sure what is the exact problem and which command will do the job.